# Updating and Deleting Records from the DataGridView and database

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, ado.net, odbc

i m new here, i want to update and delete the records from the datagridview as well as from database i have the following code for the update and delete..

```
int num = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value))
    {
        string ID = this.dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
        string CoCode = this.dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["CoCode"].Value.ToString();
        string CoName_mar = this.dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells["CoName_mar"].Value.ToString();

        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany_1.mdb";
        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblCompany_1 SET (CoCode=@CoCode,CoName_mar=@CoName_mar where ID=@ID)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CoCode", CoCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CoName_mar", CoName_mar);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", ID);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        num++;
    }
}
if (num > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated !");        
}
this.Hide();
listOfCompany v = new listOfCompany();
v.ShowDialog();
```

Add for delete records..

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany.mdb";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand ("DELETE FROM tblCompany WHERE (CoCode = i)");

con.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

1. for the update query i m getting the error that"OleDbException was handled syntax error in UPDATE" at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
2. for the delete query i m getting the error "OleDbException was handled.. Could not find installable ISAM." at `con.Open();`

how should i overcome from this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove the unnecessary parentheses:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblCompany_1 SET CoCode=@CoCode,CoName_mar=@CoName_mar where ID=@ID", con);
```

You can try putting the connection opening and closing outside the `foreach` loop so you don't have to do that every time.

2) Remove the extra space in your connection string:

```
con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany.mdb";
```

Also, you have an undefined `i` in your delete statement. Is that supposed to be a parameter?

Comment: @Barbie: If `i` is a parameter, then you have to define it and add it as such: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i", i);` where `i` should have been defined and assigned prior to the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @Barbie: What is not working? Are you not able to open a connection now? Also, change your delete statement like this: `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand ("DELETE FROM tblCompany WHERE (CoCode = @i)");`

Comment: Sorry @Alex R :- it is not working again, the error is" The name 'i' does not exist in the current context"....:(

Comment: @Barbie, That's actually a different problem from what you originally posted. Anyway, did you define `i` before adding it as a parameter? Does your program compile at all? (You may want to post your new code on a different thread/question for us to see.)

Comment: @Alex R:-   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany_1.mdb";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand ("DELETE FROM tblCompany WHERE (CoCode = @i)");

            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i", i);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();                                            This is my code

Comment: @Barbie, Yeah, you need to put `var i = 1; // or whatever value` just before `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i", i);`

Answer (score 1):

For your 2 problems:

1. Remove the parenthesis altogther after your `SET` keyword.
2. This error indicates that there's a problem with the connection string. You have an extra space in your `Data Source`. It was `Data^^Source`.

Suggest moving your .mdb to a filepath WITHOUT spaces.

```
string conn = @"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\DB\tblCompany.mdb";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The first query doesn't need parenthesis inside of the query. Replace with

   ```
   UPDATE tblCompany_1 SET CoCode=@CoCode, CoName_mar=@CoName_mar where ID=@ID
   ```
2. The delete query: What is `i`? If you have it defined you can do something like this:

   ```
   "DELETE FROM tblCompany WHERE (CoCode = " + i + ")"
   ```

   Although, using parameters would be better.

Comment: You're correct about the mystery `i` variable! Good catch! The err occurs at `con.Open()`, though.

Comment: @p.campbell - yes, you diagnosed the second issue better.

Comment: - It is giving the error that is I is not present in the current context...:(

Comment: @Barbie - I'm sorry, I can't tell you what row you need to delete. Replace i with whatever Id you need to delete.